# tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified in Sublime Text 3

Tags: bash, sublimetext3

When I build anything in Sublime Text 3 (regardless of language), I get the following lines at the beginning of any console output:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

I have no idea what shell settings ST3 is using or how to edit them. How do I get rid of this?

**EDIT**

Here are the contents of my `~/.bash_profile`, which given the comments, probably need some editing:

```
# Prompt
NRM=`tput sgr0`
BLD=`tput bold`
ITL=`tput sitm`
UL=`tput smul`
RED=`tput setaf 1`
GRN=`tput setaf 2`
BLU=`tput setaf 4`

PS1='\n\r${BLD}\u${NRM}|${UL}\h${NRM} [${BLD}${BLU}\W${NRM}] \w \n>> '

# For Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This is probably coming from your `.bashrc`. It needs to tet whether it's being used in an interactive shell, and skip things like `tput` when it's not.

Comment: Please edit your question with the contents of your `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have to change `.bash_profile` to check for interactive shell before processing any `tput` calls:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    # Prompt
    NRM=`tput sgr0`
    BLD=`tput bold`
    ITL=`tput sitm`
    UL=`tput smul`
    RED=`tput setaf 1`
    GRN=`tput setaf 2`
    BLU=`tput setaf 4`
    PS1='\n\r${BLD}\u${NRM}|${UL}\h${NRM} [${BLD}${BLU}\W${NRM}] \w \n>> '
fi
```

Comment: Could you may explain further how the `[[ $- == *i* ]]` works and why sublime text has a problem otherwise? Thank you anyway!

Comment: @A.Wenn I'm not too well-versed in `bash` but it is checking for interactive mode, which Sublime doesn't use since it is calling the bash shell indirectly. Which is important because `tput` calls only make sense and work correctly with an interactive terminal.

Comment: @A.Wenn $ refers to the current SHELL value/type. So the IF statement is asking "if your current shell mode is interactive, (i.e. you are not performing a once off tasks via ssh or some other method probably remotely), then and only then set the terminal up as such", and that's where you set your own customisations be them nice colours or welcome messages, whatever it may be. `echo $0` will in most cases give you your currently SHELL as per this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/590899/how-to-check-which-shell-am-i-using/590902#590902