# Sublime text : tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, sublimetext3

[ full error ]

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u ""]
[dir: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands]
```

all I did was print ('hello world!')

But a while ago I tried to install/update a new version of python. 
I am trying to learn to code, a while back I did one course and now I am enrolled in another and wanted to have the latest version of python. when I installed python 3.8.2 i started having an issue. 
Even downloaded my first IDE - pycharm and also has some issues. But trying to tackle one problem at a time.
Using Mac OS By the way!

Comment: Without seeing what `sublime-build` file you're using it's hard to say why the `tput` errors are being produced, so including that may help. Apart from that, your Python error is because you didn't save the file before you tried to run it the first time.

Comment: where can i find sublime-build as you suggest ? i am sorry if this is a dumb question. i am really new

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515382/tput-no-value-for-term-and-no-t-specified-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: I suspect that the build system doesn't matter in this case and that your issue is related to having things in your `.bashrc` that assume that the terminal will be interactive when it's not.

Comment: in my ~/.bash_profile i have 

cd ~/Desktop
PS1="$(tput setaf 2)[\w] \n $(tput setaf 196)$(tput sgr0)~: "

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

alias python=python3


# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the error
PS1="$(tput setaf 2)[\w] \n $(tput setaf 196)$(tput sgr0)~: "
For a better holder of your PS profile I recommend you use
PS1="\033[32m][\w] \n \033[0m]~: "

tput is usually used when coding for linux based OS, as your on Mac OS it will accept the command but also interfere with other things.
Best use the original commands for for bash as I have suggested.

Comment: You should better format the pieces of code inside your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One another solution is that, The change you made to PS1 (using `tput`) works only for interactive shells in MacOS.

Update your `.bash_profile` or `.bashsrc` with if checks.

```sh
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
     PS1="$(tput setaf 2)[\w] \n $(tput setaf 196)$(tput sgr0)~:
fi
```