# IntelliJ tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ssh

I want to run my code via SSH using IntelliJ Ultimate. During the setup, I get the error:
`Introspection completed with error. tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified`

Am I missing a package? Or how do I tell IntelliJ to use the default bash?

Comment: It could be some misconfiguration in .bash_profile or .bash_rc scripts. Please see if https://askubuntu.com/questions/591937/no-value-for-term-and-no-t-specified or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515382/tput-no-value-for-term-and-no-t-specified-in-sublime-text-3 helps

Comment: Thank you, but sadly it didn't help. I tried both solutions and the error is still occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .bash_profile contained tput, which was causing the error.